# Is it possible to bind properties to spans?

Tags: data-binding, blazor

I created a [Blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/di53zh9d) for easier understanding.
On the left hand side, you see, what I have: There is an `<input>`, two `<span>`s that display values that depend on the `<input>` and a third `<span>` that displays the sum. The `<span>`s are editable but when I edit the values, the sum is not updated.
In the middle, you see, what I want: I changed two `<span>`s to `<textarea>`s and bound their contents to the properties `Number3` and `Number4`. This enables me to have an updated sum not only when the `<input>` is changed but also when I enter a number in one of the `<textarea>`s.
These bindings work well with `<textarea>`s but not with `<span>`s. But I'd like to use `<span>`s, because no formatting is necessary (e. g. width and height) and depending on other conditions, the content should be editable or not. I realized this with `contenteditable="@(UserIsLoggedIn ? "true" : "false")"`.
On the right hand side, I tried `<span>`s but a simple `@bind="Number5"` produces an error during run time because it is interpreted as attribute and the error is

> Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@bind' is not a valid attribute name.

So I tried `@bind-value="Number5" @bind-value:event="oninput"` but this only creates an attribute named value. In the dev tools I see, there is a `<span value="2"></span>` with size 0x0, because it is empty.

Is it possible to bind properties to `<span>`s just like I bound them to the `<textarea>`s? If not, can I make a textarea look like and behave (contenteditable="false") like a span?

Comment: `bind` with `contenteditable` is not supported at the moment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9974

Comment: OK, thanks. I will then have to use a `textarea` and style it. Is it possible to set `contenteditable="false"` in a `textarea`? Or is there a more suitable `<>`-element for me?

Comment: The reason is that elements such as `span` or `div` don't have `onchange` or `oninput` events.  Just use `disabled="@true"` to enable/disable any input type control.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! My `<textarea>` now looks like this: `<textarea style="border: none;width: 40%;height: 1.5rem;background-color: transparent;color: black;resize: none;text-align: end;overflow: hidden;padding: 0;" @bind="Number4" disabled></textarea>`. With `oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/\n/g,'')"` I can even avoid that the user enters a line break.

Comment: Please note, in the `<span>`s attribute `contenteditable="@(UserIsLoggedIn ? "true" : "false")"` I passed in `"true"` and `"false"` as string. This does not work with the `disabled` attribute. It must be bools: `disabled="@(UserIsLoggedIn ? false : true)"`.